# 'warp(Vector3)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a simple fps shooter, but I get this error in the console. I had this error with the NavMeshAgent where I had to use NavMeshAgent.Warp and I tried to fix that. First I got this error `"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh` and I somehow implemented `public bool warp(Vector3 newPosition)`, but it doesn't seem to help any bit. I'm not sure if I used NavMeshAgent.Warp in my code correctly, could you help with this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int stoppingDist;
    public float coolDown;
    public float lastAtt;
    public int enemyDmg;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public GameObject target;
    public bool warp(Vector3 newPosition);

    private void Start() {
        if (agent == null)
        {
            agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
            target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        }
       
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);
        if(dist < stoppingDist){
            Stop();
            if(Time.time - lastAtt >= coolDown){
                lastAtt = Time.time;
                target.GetComponent<playerHealth>().DealDamage(enemyDmg);
            }
        }else{
            MovingToTarget();
        }
    }
   private void MovingToTarget(){
       agent.isStopped = false;
       NavMeshAgent.warp;
       agent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
   }
   private void Stop(){
       agent.isStopped = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: well what was your goal with `public bool warp(Vector3 newPosition);` ... you shouldn't implement your own method if you goal is actually calling a one that exists ;)

Comment: I tried to fix my agent as though when I started the game they'd stop on the position where the player originally spawned and not following the player

Answer (score 1):

In your code the

```
public bool warp(Vector3 newPosition);
```

makes no sense. This lags a method body doing stuff and returning a `bool` ...

You should not (try to) implement a method when actually your goal is to call an existing method of another class.

---

[`NavMeshAgent.Warp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.Warp.html) is capital `W` ...

it is also **not** `static` so what you want to call is probably rather

```
agent.Warp(newPosition);
```

where `newPosition` is a `Vector3`

> Warps agent to the provided position.

---

You probably should check if this succeeded like

```
if(agent.Warp(newPosition))
{
    agent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("Warp failed!", this);
}
```

---

Then

> "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh

hints that this agent seems to be either not active or not placed on a NavMesh ...

So you should probably also check [`NavMeshAgent.isOnNavMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-isOnNavMesh.html)

> Is the agent currently bound to the navmesh? (Read Only)
>
> This property is false if the agent, for some reason, could not bind to the navmesh. E.g. if Scene has no navmesh.

```
if(agent.isOnNavMesh)
{
    agent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("Agent is not on a NavMesh!", this);
}
```

Comment: I tried to check NavMeshAgent.isOnNavMesh, but it doesn't print anything to the console, so I assume that the agent is bound to the NavMesh, and I tried to use agent.warp(); but I kept getting this:  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'newPosition' of 'NavMeshAgent.Warp(Vector3

Comment: That's true ;) pass in a position then ;)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused.... You mean agent.position.Warp(); or..? If so I'm getting this error: 'NavMeshAgent' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'NavMeshAgent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I mean as written in the answer: `agent.Warp(somePosition);`

Comment: I made a public variable Vector3 newPosition and I put it into the agent.Warp() function, but my enemy is just frozen, and I can't even respawn them